# Spring Portlet MVC and Mobile Portal Accelerator

Tags: spring, mobile, portlet, websphere-portal

I have some portlets developed using Spring Portlet MVC framework. Currently they're deployed in a WebSphere Portal Server v7 and the work like a charm, but now the client has purchased Mobile Portal Accelerator for the Portal and wants to mobile-enable all the developed portlets using that technology.

Does anyone has any experience using that technology, specially combined with Spring Portlet MVC? IBM published [some articles about exposing existing JSR-168 portlets](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/How_To_XDIME_Enable_An_Existing_Portlet), but I'm not sure how this will work with Spring Portlet and JSR-286 API.